# How can I extract Information from open Social based networks?

Tags: data-mining, semantic-web, opensocial

How can I extract information from opensocial based networks like orkut.

Answer (score 1):

Many OpenSocial-based networks offer REST and JSON-RPC based APIs, for which there are a variety of client libraries available.

PHP is probably the most sophisticated and compatible client library (and has the best documentation).  You can find out more at this page: http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-php-client/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6